# While handling Exceptions, how to print any error statement that occurs? See below for more details

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

Suppose -

```
a, b, c, d = 2, 0, 3, "$"
try:
    print (a//b)
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
    print (e)
try:
    print (c//d)
```

I know this is a type error, but how do I print the error statement without knowing what error to expect (in general)? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use base `Exception` to catch other errors:

```
a, b, c, d = 2, 0, 3, "$"
try:
    print (a//b)
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
    print (e)
except Exception as e:
    print (e)
```

Comment: you should avoid `except Exception` because it's too broad, but it is very helpful at the beginning of development